# Simple example of using data from a YAML configuration file in a Perl script

Tags: perl, yaml

I need to create a YAML file to store some configuration data for a Perl script. This seems like it should be really easy but I haven't been able to work it out, I think if I had just one simple example to copy I'd be fine. I want to do something like this:

```
-----test.yaml-----
image_width: 500
show_values: 0
-------------------

------test.perl------
use YAML;

my (%settings) = Load('test.yaml');
print "The image width is", $settings{image_width};
---------------------
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use YAML qw(LoadFile);

my $settings = LoadFile('test.yaml');
say "The image width is ", $settings->{image_width};
```

– Michael

Answer (score 14):

Your fundamental problem here is that `Load` expects a string containing YAML, not a filename.  You wanted `LoadFile` instead (which is not exported by default).  Also, you should use [YAML::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML::XS) instead of [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML) if you can, as it's a better implementation.  (But YAML should be adequate for a simple config file.)

The other problem is that `LoadFile` will return a hash reference (well, if your YAML looks like a hash, as yours does), not a list you can use to initialize a hash.

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML::XS qw(LoadFile);

my $settings = LoadFile('test.yaml');

print "The image width is ", $settings->{image_width};
```

(You can delete the `::XS` if you don't want to (or can't) install YAML::XS.  The program will work with no other changes.)

Comment: For config files I prefer YAML::Tiny.

Answer (score 7):

Try dumping out the configuration you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML;

my %settings = (
        foo => 1,
        bar => [qw/one two three/],
);

print Dump(\%settings);
```

This prints

```
---
bar:
  - one
  - two
  - three
foo: 1
```

Also, wikipedia has a good [overview of YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) if the specification is a bit too dense.

Comment: +1; I do this from the command line all the time: `perl -MYAML::Any -wle'my $data = { some data here }; print Dump($data)'`  It's also a good idea to unyamlize any config file you make and call Data::Dumper against it, to verify that you made the changes you intended to.

Comment: I do the same thing. It's a lot easier for me to get the initial file correct this way than it is if I start from scratch.

Comment: While this is a good way to create a YAML config file, it doesn't address the problem he has with his code.  His YAML is actually usable; it's the code that doesn't work.