# Perl:YAML iterate in the Array?

Tags: perl, yaml

i am following on this example [Simple example of using data from a YAML configuration file in a Perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453573/simple-example-of-using-data-from-a-yaml-configuration-file-in-a-perl-script)

vihtorr@w00w /var/www $ cat test.yaml

```
IPs: [500, 600, 200, 100]
```

vihtorr@w00w /var/www $ cat yam2.pl

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use YAML::XS qw(LoadFile); 

 my $settings = LoadFile('test.yaml');
 print "The IPs are ", $settings->{IPs};
```

and i would like to know who to iterate inside the Array?

when i execute the code i get

```
perl yam2.pl 
The IPs are ARRAY(0x166e5e0)
```

thanks for helping a noob

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$settings->{IPs}
```

holds a reference to an array. Arrays are dereferenced using

```
@{ $ref }       # The whole thing
${ $ref }[$i]   # One element
$ref->[$i]      # One element
@{ $ref }[@i]   # Array slice
```

so you can access the array using

```
@{ $settings->{IPs} }
```

You get:

```
print "The IPs are ", join(', ', @{ $settings->{IPs} }), "\n";
```

You might also be interseted in

```
for my $ip (@{ $settings->{IPs} }) {
   ... do something with $ip ...
}
```

References:

- [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)
- [References Quick Reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

Comment: @ikegami can you please provide the same but for a HASH?

Comment: @Vihtorr, "%" instead of "@", "{ }" instead of "[ ]". See the first ref I linked!

Comment: @ikegami thanks for the link, but i am very new to ref on perl.. i saw it but i am struggling on the syntax and the logic - i have raised this question again and see if a skilled expert like you can answer it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549866/perlyamlhash-how-to-select-an-entry

Answer (score 1):

The ARRAY(0x166e5e0) output shows that $settings->{IPs} is an array reference. You must dereference it to iterate:

```
for my $ip (@{$settings->{IPs}}) {
   print $ip . "\n";
}
```

If all you need to do is print, you can just use join():

```
print join("\n", @{$settings->{IPs}});
```