# Perl:YAML:Hash How to select an entry?

Tags: perl, yaml

Greetings Perl Experts

Based on the YAML file below, and this example [Perl:YAML iterate in the Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549021/perlyaml-iterate-in-the-array)  can someone please be so kind to show me a perl example where i can select the countrie and print out the cities  i have been?

```
USA:
    BeenThere: [Miami, Denver, Las Vegas, Chicago]
    ToVisit:   [Los Angeles, Boston]
Europe:
    BeenThere: [Paris, Amsterdam, Dublin, Bulgaria, Madrid]
    ToVisit:   [Budapest, Belgrad]
Latam:
     BeenThere: [Venezuela, Bogota]
     ToVisit:   [Argentina, San Paulo]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I recommend [Mark's very short tutorial about references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to get the info for each country, or just a specific one?

Specific one:

```
my $country_name = '...';
my $country = $data->{$country_name};
my $visited = $country->{BeenThere};
for my $city_name (@$visited) {
   say $city_name;
}
```

All:

```
for my $country_name (keys %$data) {
   my $country = $data->{$country_name};
   my $visited = $country->{BeenThere};
   for my $city_name (@$visited) {
      say "$city_name, $country_name";
   }
}
```

Comment: not sure why is not working, but thank you very much


DB<3> s
main::(yam3.pl:7): my $country = $data->{$country_name};
  DB<3> l
7==> my $country = $data->{$country_name};
8: my $visited = $country->{BeenThere};
9: for my $city_name (@$visited) {
10:    say $city_name;
11  }
12  
13  
  DB<3> p $country_name
USA
  DB<4> s
main::(yam3.pl:8): my $visited = $country->{BeenThere};
  DB<4> l
8==> my $visited = $country->{BeenThere};
9: for my $city_name (@$visited) {
10:    say $city_name;
11  }
12  
13  
  DB<4> p $country

  DB<5> q
vihtorr@w00w /var/www $

Comment: It's working fine except for the missing semi-colon. Added. Header: `use strict; use warnings; use feature qw( say ); use YAML::XS qw(LoadFile); my $data = LoadFile('test.yaml');`

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you define "Select", this might help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML::XS qw(LoadFile);

my $data = LoadFile('test.yaml');

for my $city (@{$data->{USA}{BeenThere}}) {
  print("$city ");
}
```

Each country is a hash reference and the cities are array references (handled like the link you passed).